# Take information from the database always returns -1

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I'm new to programming on android and I can't understand why taking integer values from the SQLite database always returns -1.
My application is composed of the Main activity where I create if the database does not already exist and populates the first line with all zeros in this way

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
Cursor data = databaseHelper.getInformation();
if(!data.moveToFisrt()) {
    databaseHelper.addInformation(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now I start the second activity that implements a custom view. In this activity I implement a custom view and inside the custom view I update the row previously created in the main activity, then I call the adInformation method in this way

SecondActivity

```
private CustomView cv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    
    cv= new CustomView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
}
```

CustomView

```
//all the constructors call init()
private void init(Context context){
        /***/
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        int w, l, d;
        Cursor data = databaseHelper.getInformation();
        w = data.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(1));
        l = data.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(2));
        d = data.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(3));
        //here w,l,d are -1
    }
```

This is my database helper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME1+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, W INT, D INT, L INT)");
        //i have a second table
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME1);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addInformation(int w, int l, int d){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        if(w != -1) {
            values.put("W", w);
        }
        if(d != -1)
            values.put("D", d);
        if(l != -1)
            values.put("L", l);

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, values);

        db.close();
        if(id == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }

    public Cursor getInformation(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return c;
    }
}
```

I also note that my database contains a second table. This second tab is populated inside the custom view and is then displayed when I return to the main activity.
The records inserted in the custom view appear correctly in the main activity.
Moreover if in the custom view I had to call first getInformation, then addInformation (5,5,5) and after getInformation () it would return -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getColumnIndex turns a column name into a column number.  Unless your columns are named "1", "2", and "3" this code isn't correct.  I think you wanted `getInt(getColumnIndex("name of column"))`

Remember that the order of columns returned by a SELECT * is arbitrary, so don't assume what's in 1, 2, and 3.  Instead use the code I posted above with "W", "D", and "L"

Comment: You are completely right. I thought I was doing data.getInt (column index).